# gradle get resources default output directory

Tags: gradle, directory, resources, output, source-sets

Gradle: how to get default resources output dir?

```
println sourceSets.main.resources.outputDir
```

Error:

```
Needs to set a non-null value before it can be retrieved
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this :

```
println sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir
```

[Source](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:working_with_java_source_sets)

Comment: Link to docs: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.html

Answer (score 5):

For kotlin DSL:

```
sourceSets.main.get().output.resourcesDir
```

Comment: `sourceSets.main.get().output.resourcesDir` is a `File` type. To cast it to String, we should call `sourceSets.main.get().output.resourcesDir.toString()`